# Does `across` works with summarize for dplyr spark frames?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am having issues using `summarize` in conjunction with the `across` and `where` verbs when using a `tbl_spark` instead of a regular `tbl`.

**Initializing Tibble**

```
temp <- tibble(
  a = c(1, 2, NA),
  c = c(4, 8, NA),
  b = c("A", NA, "B")
)

temp_spark <- sdf_copy_to(sc, temp, "temp_spark")
```

**My Attempt**

```
> temp %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a     c
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.5     6
> temp_spark %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
  no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "function"
```